# Why would odds ratio be more useful than difference of probabilities?

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I'm curious on why the odds ratio would be useful?

For example, suppose I designed an experiment and fit a logistic regression model for success rate data. $p(success|treatment) = sigmoid(treatment*B_1 + B_0)$ where treatment is binary.

So if I want to know the lift attributable to treatment, I can query it as
$sigmoid(B_1 + B_0) - sigmoid(B_0)$.

However, I've read that the odds ratio, $exp(B_1)$, is actually more useful.

Could someone explain why this might be the case?

Comment: The odds ratio is perhaps technically more facile. Usually the hypothesis we want to test is if $p_1 > p_2$. This means that the hypothesis can be trivially reexpressed as $p_1-p_2 > 0 $, $p_1/p_2 > 1$ or $p_1/(1-p_1) / (p_2/(1-p_2)) >1$ which is, respectively, the risk difference (RD), risk ratio (RR), and odds ratio (OR). A risk difference is a little misleading when the outcome is rare, like we can say the risk of a type of cancer is 0.0003 higher in those with a risk factor, but the risk ratio might 20 or higher!

Answer (score 0):

What is "useful" depends on your application.

However, consider a more complication logistic regression e.g. regression of `success` against `treatment + age` where age is a numeric. If you use the odds, you can easily partition out the effect of `treatment` from the effect of `age`.

Comment: Odds ratio compares odds(x) to odds(not x) right? The marginalization makes it easier to generalize- or am I confused

Comment: @AlexJ this is a partial answer in my opinion. There exists, for instance, multivariate models for risk difference. Consider `glm(success  ~ treatment + age, family=binomial(link='identity'))`.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 An odds ratio is a product moment summary, just like a correlation, that compares two groups based on an exposure, in the distribution of the outcome. Odds(x) and odds(not x) are definitionally inverses of each other. I think you mean to point out that odds(x) = p(x)/p(not x) - a value which ranges from 0 to $\infty$, take the logarithm and the support of this measure is all real values, and the associations are all real values. It bounds the possible response levels and thus prevents overprediction (getting fitted probabilities that are greater than 1 or less than 0).